# Giving command line arguments to executable being run with ltrace/strace

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, strace, ltrace

The title says it all friends!

How do I give command line arguments to an executable whose execution I want to monitor using ltrace/strace ?

For example, if the executable is 'a.out' and I want to store ltrace's output in a file 'out.txt' and 'arg1' is a command line argument that I want to pass to the execuable, then the command I tried is this
      "ltrace ./a.out -o arg1 out.txt"

The problem is my program is designed to work only for a single command line argument, so when I run the above command, my program interprets this as multiple command line arguments and stops execution after printing a "Usage" message (it is actually designed to do this but here I want to monitor the library calls it is making).

Can someone please help me out ?  Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try passing `-o` before the command to execute:

```
ltrace -o out.txt ./a.out arg1
```

This way `ltrace` will get `-o out.txt` and then will exec `a.out`, passing to it the rest of the command line.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick. Can't believe I didn't try this myself :)

Comment: Cool. Also, for vexing command lines you might also want to look into `--` (search for ["unix double dash"](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html)) although you don't need it in this case.